# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not firing on cells when UITableView is added as subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a regular `UIViewController` to which I have added a `UITableView` in`viewDidLoad`, like this:

```
dataTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 320, 318)];
dataTableView.dataSource = self;

[self.view addSubview:dataTableView];
```

**It's working fine**, the cell contents are there, which I added via the call to `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. I can scroll and everything, **but I can't get the cells to react to touch/click.** When I press a cell, it stays selected, but I can't seem to attach an action to it. The code I'm using is

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"select");
}
```

But it never fires. Do I have to make some sort of connection between the tableview and the call? If so, why does it work for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` without problem? Any help is appreciated. I'm sure this is simple to fix for somebody who knows their "Objective-C"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set yourself up as the delegate of the `dataTableView`.

```
dataTableView.delegate = self;
```

The reason that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` works is because that's part of the `dataSource` whereas `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is part of the `delegate`.

Comment: YES! That was it. Now I feel stupid for posting the question in the first place.  

A Note: When I first inserted the line, the app crashed on me. I had to insert it before `dataTableView.dataSource = self;` for it to work. Probably clear to most people, but I thought I'd mention it for beginners having the same problem in the future. Thanks for the speedy reply!